# create a mobile wallet for my ERC20

Tags: wallets, android, ios

Does anyone know if is there any open source code mobile wallet (Android or IOS) that i can use to store and transfer my custom ERC20 token.

I would like to be able to modify it in order to allow it to store only my custom token, i mean, lets say i create xyzToken (ERC20) so i would like to have XYZapp, where i can handle my balance and transfer the token to other users.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at this? It is erc-20 compatible.

https://github.com/walleth

Answer (score 1):

For iOS here is an example, how to work with ERC20 tokens:

https://github.com/matterinc/DiveLane